# Return key keyboard iOS Textfield

Tags: xcode

So, I've some code here, and I want to know how I can disable the keyboard if I'm done with typing in a textfield by pressing the return key in the keyboard. I want this: If textfield.text is equal to @"kshglfjds" ... set imageView to @"image"

But I don't know how I can write that code....

Sreenshots of the .h en .m file:
[image: .h]

[image: .m]

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html

Answer (score 2):

Set some object (your view controller perhaps?) to be the delegate of your text field, then you can inspect the content of the text field when the field is done being edited by implementing this delegate method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if([textField.text compare: @"kshglfjds" ] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
         // make your image visible
    }
}
```

Ugh, now that I'm reviewing your question again... I realize your question is not clear at all.  If you want to *dismiss* the keyboard after hitting return, do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)hideKeyboard {

    [sender resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Connect it to the TextField(s) as `Did End on Exit`. If you use `sender` instead of `textField` you can connect it to more than 1 TextField, because TextField 1 has for example the name `textField` and the second `textField2`, but if you use `sender` it detects which TextField is calling the method. Otherwise you need to have 1 void for every TextField, like this:

```
- (void)hideKeyboard1 {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}

- (void)hideKeyboard2 {

    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];

}
```